# Проблема с редиректами Django Apache + Cloudflare

Tags: django, .htaccess, redirect, apache2, http-status-code-301

Всем привет, у меня такая ситуация, выгрузил сайт на сервер, подключил Cloudflare, нужно было настроить редиректы со страниц старого сайта на новые, мне выдали список 500 страниц, я записал все это в htaccess, проверил ответ каждой страницы скриптом, везде 200, то есть все ок.
но путем мануального тестирования выявил некоторые проблемы, например:
вот правило из htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/publ/instrukcii/1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://vipkeys.net/blog/instrukcii? [R=301,L]
```

Но если перейти по ссылке **https://www.vipkeys.net/publ/instrukcii/1** то выдается 404 и ссылка превращается в **https://vipkeys.net/bloginstrukcii/1**.
Но если смотреть через всякие сервисы то все как бы нормально.

То есть проблема появляется только если пытаться физически перейти на эту страницу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чем может быть причина, и в какую сторону копать?

вот еще примеры

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/microsoft-windows/windows-11$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://vipkeys.net/shop/windows-11/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/microsoft-windows/windows-10$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://vipkeys.net/shop/windows-10/? [R=301,L]
```

с https://www.vipkeys.net/shop/microsoft-windows/windows-11
редиректит на https://vipkeys.net/shop/windows-11/ как и должно, но вот
с https://www.vipkeys.net/shop/microsoft-windows/windows-10 редиректит вообще не туда https://vipkeys.net/shop/windows//windows-10